# Validate Vat number in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

VAT numbers are not randomly or sequentially generated but are based on a formula that can be checked to see if the number is valid. If a VAT number is invalid a business cannot re-claim the VAT.

To validate a UK VAT number manually you can perform the following exercise:

Excluding the first 2 letters, list the numbers vertically and multiply each by a value starting with 8 and ending with 2. Then add up all the sums you have and deduct 97 from the sum until the answer is negative. The negative sum should be equal to the last 2 digits of the VAT number.

So for example, the VAT number for `BLABLA` is GB 815382334 the calculation is:

```
8 x 8 = 64
1 x 7 = 7 
5 x 6 = 30 
3 x 5 = 15 
8 x 4 = 32 
2 x 3 = 6 
3 x 2 = 6
```

The total of the above calculation is `64 + 7 + 30 + 15 + 32 + 6 + 6 = 160`
Deduct 97 from this until the result is negative, the result is `160 – 97 - 97= -34` which is the same as the last two digits: so the VAT number is valid.

I want to write a C# application that takes a UK VAT Number as input, calculates the checksum using the above formula, and indicates if the number is valid or invalid.

This is for me an exercise in algorithm's. I have found vat checkers online but I don't understand how they are working, so I was hoping some one could give some simple answers to the above problem with good explanations?

**Update**:

```
    public static bool isValidVATNumber(string theVATNumber)
    {
        string startChar = "^";
        string endChar = "$";
        bool rtn = false;
        int i = 8;
        string valString;
        int sum = 0;
        // Check that the string matches the requirements
        rtn = Regex.IsMatch(theVATNumber, (startChar + ("(([1-9]d{8})|([1-9]d{11}))" + endChar)), RegexOptions.Multiline);
        if (rtn)
        {
            // Perform the validation
            valString = theVATNumber;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(valString, (startChar + "[A-Z]{2}"), RegexOptions.Multiline))
            {
                valString = valString.Substring(2);
            }
            while ((i >= 2))
            {
                sum = (sum
                            + (i * int.Parse(valString.Substring(0, 1))));
                valString = valString.Substring(1);
                i--;
            }
            while ((sum > 0))
            {
                sum -= 97;
            }
            rtn = ((sum * -1)
                        == int.Parse(valString));
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

Note the above method does not work and for me more difficult to understand, I started with my own method that I find much easier to work with but yet to finish it (please note it is embarrassing)

```
    List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
    int b = 8;

    for (int a = 0; a < textBox1.Text.Length; a++)
    {
        integerList.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text[a].ToString())); 
    }
    foreach (int item in integerList) 
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item * b);
        --b; 
    }
```

I still have to take the sum of the list and do the rest of the calculations and was hoping to pick some peoples brains as to other ways it might be done (easier ways).

Update on my own method and abit of thanks to Pax below:

```
    List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
    List<int> sumList = new List<int>();
    int b = 8; // Will be 8 for the first multiplication.

    for (int a = 0; a <= 6; a++)
    {
        integerList.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text[a].ToString())); 
    }
    foreach (int item in integerList) // Loop once per input digit.
    {

        //listBox1.Items.Add(item * b);
        sumList.Add(item * b);
        --b; 
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = sumList;

    int sum = sumList.Sum();

    while (sum > 0)
    {
        sum = sum - 97;
    }
    int myInt = System.Math.Abs(sum);
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(myInt);
```

Comment: It's an interesting problem, but what have you tried and what is your level of understanding of C# ? The algorithm should be rather straight forward if you have a basic understanding.  A tip would be to look at getting a string representation of the VAT number, and use an array operator to get the value of it, char by char ...

Comment: @KirstyWhite And to get better you keep on trying, you let people see what you've done (even if you think it's embarassingly wrong), you take advice and constructive criticism, you ignore the trolls and the doubts and all those things that tell you you're useless at it and you never give up.  Part of the reason places like this exist, to allow people to try and improve.

Comment: @Russ C: or the more math solution - to use `%`

Comment: Your initial formula is not correct for 2 reasons - since 2010 HMRC issues numbers with a 9755 checksum - so % 97 then subtract 55.  Also a zero in the number should be counted as 10 (so a number starting 104 is 1*8 + 10*7 + 4*6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, let's look at this bit by bit. Say you have the code `815382334` - you've already removed the irrelevant characters at the front.

The first step is a matter of looping through the characters and maintaining a running total of the numeric value multiplied by the index), in pseudo-code:

```
sum = 0
for pos = 0 to 6 inclusive:
    sum = sum + num_at(pos) * (8 - pos)
```

For each iteration of the loop above, you extract the correct number from the string and multiply it by its index, which starts at `8` and goes down to `2`. Then that gets added to the `sum` variable. Keep in mind that the `num_at()` method needs to give you an integer from zero through nine inclusive, *not* the character code itself, which is likely to be `0x30` through `0x39`.

I often find that it's easier for beginners to sit down and run the program using their noggin as the CPU and a bit of paper for storage, such as:

```
pos  num_at(pos)  8-pos  add  sum
---  -----------  -----  ---  ---
                                0
 0        8          8    64   64
 1        1          7     7   71
 2        5          6    30  101
 3        3          5    15  116
 4        8          4    32  148
 5        2          3     6  154
 6        3          2     6  160
```

The second step, you subtract 97 until you go negative, as per the specification:

```
while sum > 0:
    sum = sum - 97
```

(although you could probably use the modulo operator more efficiently). And, again, running it inside your head:

```
sum
---
160
 63
 34-
```

Then, as the third and final step, add back the last two digits (as a full two-digit number) to make sure you get zero:

```
sum = sum + num_at(7) * 10 + num_at(8)
return (sum == 0);
```

Since the numbers at positions 7 and 8 are `3` and `4` respectively, `num_at(7) * 10 + num_at(8)` will give you `34`, which is what you want to add back to the negatively adjusted sum.

The modulo version allows for something like:

```
sum = 0
for pos = 0 to 6 inclusive:
    sum = sum + num_at(pos) * (8 - pos)
return ((sum % 97) + num_at(7) * 10 + num_at(8) == 97);
```

This works because `sum % 97` is effectively the same as the loop giving you a negative number but *without* the final subtraction of 97. Hence, when you add back the final two digits, you'll get 97 rather than 0 (for a valid VAT number).

By way of example, `160 % 97` gives you `63` and `63 + 34` gives you `97`.

---

Now, based on your added code fragment, you probably need to handle both types of VAT number, those with 9 digits and those with 12 digits. The code fragment posted is probably a little more complex than necessary with all its regex checking and substringing where length checks, simple string indexing and character checking would suffice.

Comment: Yeah thanks pax like I said already checked the net and already have this method but its still abit hard for me to understand.

Comment: If you can't translate the above from pseudo-code into actual code, then you probably need to go through some more basic tutorials/practice first. (Not trying to be rude...just trying to help out without doing it for you, because doing it for you isn't the best way to learn...)

Comment: @Kirsty, I've added some more explanatory notes which should hopefully help out.

Comment: Its not that I cant translate its that i dont understand it. Hence why I came here for help on something a little more simple. I have the above method already and I will post it in a sec if this damm update 3 would ever finish!

Comment: Thanks Pax, explanation is starting to sound way better! However bit lost here: `sum = sum + num_at(7) * 10 + num_at(8)` I have also updated my question with the method I was trying out.

Comment: @Kirsty, further explanation of the `x*10+y` bit given.

Comment: Thanks pax, managed to use your method and my own method. Only last thing I need to do is compare myInt with the last two digits.

Answer (score 2):

My approach in C# would be as follows... I've tested it quickly with a few values but make sure you test it properly before using it. I've tried to choose code that shows clarity of intent rather than performance so some bits could be optimised, but I don't think it would be worth the effort unless you are doing millions of validations.

```
public static class VAT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a GB VAT number
    /// </summary>
    public static bool ValidateGBVatNumber(string vatNumber)
    {
        vatNumber = vatNumber.Replace(" ", "").ToUpperInvariant();
        if (vatNumber.Length == 11)
        {
            if (vatNumber[0] == 'G' && vatNumber[1] == 'B')
            {
                vatNumber = vatNumber.Substring(2);
            }
            else
            {
                // First digits are not GB
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (vatNumber.Length != 9)
        {
            // Wrong length even after removing spaces and getting rid of the first two characters
            return false;
        }

        // Provided number has 9 digits, which is correct. Proceed to calculate checksum
        int runningTotal = 0;
        int[] multipliersByIndex = new int[] {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2};
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            int currentDigitValue;
            if (!int.TryParse(vatNumber[i].ToString(), out currentDigitValue))
            {
                // Could not parse a digit into an int => wrong character supplied
                return false;
            }
            runningTotal += currentDigitValue * multipliersByIndex[i];
        }

        // Subtract 97 until negative - this could perhaps be better done with the modulus operator
        // but this way might be more 'obvious'
        while (runningTotal >= 0)
        {
            runningTotal -= 97;
        }

        // Convert to a string that will have two digits even if the number only has one
        string checkSum = (runningTotal * -1).ToString("00");

        return (checkSum[0] == vatNumber[7] && checkSum[1] == vatNumber[8]);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
isValid = VAT.ValidateGBVatNumber("GB 815382334"); // True
isValid = VAT.ValidateGBVatNumber("GB815382334"); // True
isValid = VAT.ValidateGBVatNumber("815382334"); // True
isValid = VAT.ValidateGBVatNumber("GB 815382335"); // False
isValid = VAT.ValidateGBVatNumber("GB 81538233424242"); // False
isValid = VAT.ValidateGBVatNumber("YHUWOCNYEX"); // False
```